# Content div filling all available height, with auto-size width wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to create a cross-browser compatible website with this layout (sorry for the ugly template) :

http://www.sim3media.com/stuff/layout.png

I have tried a few different solutions but none seem to work (flex-box, absolute positioning).

Here is the link to my current code :

http://www.sim3media.com/test/index.html

Here is my current code.

CSS:

```
.row { overflow: hidden; position: absolute; }
.scroll-y { overflow-y: auto; }

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 320px;
    position: relative;
}

header.row {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

content.row {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    top: 140px;
    bottom: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

footer.row {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <header class='row'>
            Header
    </header>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
    <content class='row scroll-y'>
        Content<br/>
    </content>
</div>

<footer class='row'>
    Footer
</footer>
```

If I use "position: relative" in my wrapper, my wrapper will function properly. However, my content div will not use 100% of the available height. On the other hand, if I do not use "position: relative" in my wrapper, my content div will use all of the available height, as it should, but the wrapper itself will not work properly (content and header background will overflow to the right). If you use index2.html instead of index.html in the link I provided above, you will see what I mean (cannot post both links since I do not have enough reputation).

Are there any full-browser compatible solutions to achieve this result? I would prefer not using Javascript to do so, but am open to the idea if I have no choice.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think you should definitely be using a flex layout for this. It can be quite confusing first (at least it was for me), but when you get the hang of it, it is a very powerful tool! I recommend these two sites to look at for information:  
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  ,  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes  
(also, remembert to use the "flex:" shothand, and I don't think you need those wrappers.)

Comment: I was under the impression that it would be hard to attain older browser compatibility with Flex, but upon further research it seems I was mistaken.

This is definitely something I will have to look into for the future. Thank you for your answer.

Here is an article that explains how to get more browser compatibility :

https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the div.wrapper around `<content>`, it's just complicating things.

Once div.wrapper is removed, on `<content>` use these rules:

```
top: 140px;
bottom: 140px;
min-height: 200px;
max-width: 1200px;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
width: 100%;
```

This is using the `left:50% / translate -50%` trick to center horizontally. [Checkout this article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) to learn more about dynamic centering in CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the article!

It works perfectly!

Comment: I added these to the code to increase browser compatibility :

 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);